# XmlSerializer "System.InvalidOperationException" when I use property order

Tags: asp.net

### Why is XmlSerializer throwing an InvalidOperationException, when I use Order ( [XmlElement(ElementName = "name",Order = 1)]) in my class? But I use [XmlElement(ElementName = "name"] - XmlSerializer is ok. Help please

My_Class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElement
{
    private string nameField;

    private shipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementTranslations translationsField;

    private sbyte isPublicField;

    private string orderNrField;

    private string originField;

    private string studyGroupField;

    private ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementLogic[] logicsField;

    private string idField;

    private string parentField;

    private string parentRefTypeField;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Order = 1)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.nameField; }
        set { this.nameField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "translations", Order = 2)]
    public shipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementTranslations Translations
    {
        get { return this.translationsField; }
        set { this.translationsField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isPublic", Order = 3)]
    public sbyte IsPublic
    {
        get { return this.isPublicField; }
        set { this.isPublicField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "integer", ElementName = "orderNr", Order = 4)]
    public string OrderNr
    {
        get { return this.orderNrField; }
        set { this.orderNrField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "origin", Order = 5)]
    public string Origin
    {
        get { return this.originField; }
        set { this.originField = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string StudyGroup
    {
        get { return this.studyGroupField; }
        set { this.studyGroupField = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "form", Order = 6)] public ElementForm ElementForm;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "variable", Order = 7)] public ElementVariable ElementVariable;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("logic", IsNullable = false)]
    public ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementLogic[] Logics
    {
        get { return this.logicsField; }
        set { this.logicsField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.idField; }
        set { this.idField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Parent
    {
        get { return this.parentField; }
        set { this.parentField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ParentRefType
    {
        get { return this.parentRefTypeField; }
        set { this.parentRefTypeField = value; }
    }
}
```

### My serializer:

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(My_Class));
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\test.xml"))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, My_Class);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVqiD.png)

Comment: What is not ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
Writing attributes for all public properties:
---------------------------------------------
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "shipDataDictionaryHierarchyElement")]
    public class ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElement
    {
        private string nameField;
        private shipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementTranslations translationsField;

        private sbyte isPublicField;
        private string orderNrField;
        private string originField;
        private string studyGroupField;
        private ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementLogic[] logicsField;
        private string idField;
        private string parentField;
        private string parentRefTypeField;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.nameField; }
            set { this.nameField = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "translations")]
        public shipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementTranslations Translations
        {
            get { return this.translationsField; }
            set { this.translationsField = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "isPublic")]
        public sbyte IsPublic
        {
            get { return this.isPublicField; }
            set { this.isPublicField = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "integer", ElementName = "orderNr")]
        public string OrderNr
        {
            get { return this.orderNrField; }
            set { this.orderNrField = value; }
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "origin")]
        public string Origin
        {
            get { return this.originField; }
            set { this.originField = value; }
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string StudyGroup
        {
            get { return this.studyGroupField; }
            set { this.studyGroupField = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "form")]
      public ElementForm ElementForm { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "variable")]
        public ElementVariable ElementVariable { get; set; }



        [XmlArrayItem("logic", IsNullable = false)]
        public ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElementLogic[] Logics
        {
            get { return this.logicsField; }
            set { this.logicsField = value; }
        }


        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName ="id", DataType = "integer")]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return this.idField; }
            set { this.idField = value; }
        }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "parent")]
        public string Parent
        {
            get { return this.parentField; }
            set { this.parentField = value; }
        }


        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "parentRefType")]
        public string ParentRefType
        {
            get { return this.parentRefTypeField; }
            set { this.parentRefTypeField = value; }
        }

        public ShipDataDictionaryHierarchyElement() { }

    }
```

> **and WRITE ATTRIBUTES for my_type properties:**

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class ElementVariable
    {
        ..................

        public ElementVariable() { }
 }
```

> ```
> and
> ```

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "form", IsNullable = false)]
  public class ElementForm
    {
..............
    }
```

> **result:**

```
     <hierarchyElements>
        <hierarchyElement id="1" parent="" parentRefType="">
          <name></name>
          <translations idRef="0" idRefType="xml" />
          <isPublic></isPublic>
          <orderNr></orderNr>
          <form>
            <formOrder></formOrder>
            <studyGeneration></studyGeneration>
            <ignoreClosedVisit></ignoreClosedVisit>
          </form>
        </hierarchyElement>
```

All the properties class serialized in ordered, but property [XmlElement(Order = 1)] not working.

### The problem is solved partially